# Action not defined in controller cakephp

Tags: url, cakephp

I am having this issue while using findbyid to get a unique url for a page on my shared hosting. The problem I have is that I keep getting the following error while trying to access the unique page via the Id number of the item on shared hosting(i dont get this issue on localhost):

```
 Error: The action item is not defined in controller ProductsController
Error: Create ProductsController::item() in file: app/Controller/ProductsController.php.
```

However item is defined in the productscontroller:

```
     public function item($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('product not found'));
    }

    $items = $this->Product->findById($id);


    if (!$items) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }
    $this->set('item', $items);
}
```

you can see the problem at this url: http://entourmag.com/hava/products/item/39

it works on localhost via wamp so I am not sure what the problem is.

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your contoller actually named `ProductsController` (plural and camelcase)? and the file is `ProductsController.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out the issue. The problem was with the files uploaded; the files uploaded were incomplete or missing, when I check the ProductsController.php file I realised that most of the code was missing. Reuploading solved the problem.

For others with problematic internet connection take note of this while coding.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. I couldn't figure out a scenario that would trigger that precise error message, other that actually having a `ProductsController` class without such action.

Answer (score 0):

Error: A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to connect.
The database server returned this error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_connection.ctp

I think you have not created/configured your database.php in app/Config

Comment: Was trying to update the code and some of the uploading failed, that is why that came up. It doesnt really have any relation to the problem I had which is now solved.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am using cakephp 3.8 and I figure out one possible cause of this kind of messages.

In my case, I am expecting the `__construct` method is responsible for creating the base class.

And the solution is to use `initialize` method, like so:

```php
function initialize() {
  parent::initialize();
}
```

In conclusion, we should more carefully read the documentation, it clearly stated [here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#the-app-controller) and please take time to do the [20 min cms tutorial](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/installation.html)